# Calculate a function from a number in a vector and store the result in an array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have an array of numbers.

```
S = [a_1,a_2,...,a_n]
```

How would I calculate the following function on each element in the array, and store the result in the adjacent cell next to the original element creating a 2x2 matrix?

```
T = [a_1, 1/(n+1); ...; a_i, i/(n+1); ...; a_n, n/n+1]
```

For the aforementioned matrix, 'i' represents the index, and 'n' represents the total number of elements. Is there a more efficient method than iterating through each element in a for loop? If I have to run this function on three such vectors, would a for loop be the best option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, if I understood your question correctly:

```
n=length(S)
T=[S;(1:n)/(n+1)]'
```

Comment: I get the following error: "Error using vertcat CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent."

Comment: @idealistikz that's because your S is probably a column vector and not a row vector as you presented in the question. Just transpose it S=S'.

Comment: How would I do this for a column vector without transposing?

Comment: @idealistikz if S is a column vector and you don't want to transpose it (although I can't see why you would not want to transpose it), use T=[S,(1:n)'/(n+1)]